# Find object with given id in nested arrays with ramda, get all properties except children array

Tags: ramda.js

I have an object with nested arrays, like this

```
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: "first",
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "second",
      children: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "third",
      children: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "fourth",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I need to build a function with ramda to recursive iterate over it and find inner object with specific "id" property, then omit its children.

```
console.log(findById(1, obj)); // => {id: 1, name: "first"}
console.log(findById(2, obj)); // => {id: 2, name: "second"}
console.log(findById(3, obj)); // => {id: 3, name: "third"}
console.log(findById(4, obj)); // => {id: 4, name: "fourth"}
```

My current solution looks ugly and doesn't work as expected

```
function findById(id, obj) {
  if (R.propEq("id", id)(obj)) {
    return R.omit(["children"])(obj);
  }

  if (!R.isEmpty(R.prop("children", obj))) {
    return R.map((obj) => findById(id, obj), R.prop("children", obj));
  }
}



 >   Object {id: 1, name: "first"}
 >   [Object]
 >   [Array[2]]
 >   [Array[2]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using recursion and just two Ramda functions:

1. One is the predicate function - it checks that an object has the required property
2. The second is the transformation function - it transforms the object (omits `children`)

These two functions *may* also be in plain JavaScript. (I leave this to you as an exercise.)

The function takes a list of objects:

1. If the first object satisfies the predicate then transform it and return it.
2. Otherwise reapply the function on a new list which can be either the first object children (if any) or the rest of the original list. (In that order.)
3. The special symbol `Empty` marks the end of the recursion if no object satisfied the predicate

As Scott suggested you can use that function to build another function more specific to your needs:

```
const findById = (id, obj) =>
  findWith(propEq('id', id), omit(['children']), [obj]);
```

```js
const Empty = Symbol();

// General all-purpose function
const findWith = (predicate, transform, [first = Empty, ...rest]) =>
  first === Empty
    ? null
    : predicate(first)
      ? transform(first)
      : findWith(predicate, transform, first.children) ||
        findWith(predicate, transform, rest);
        
        
// Your specific function
const findById = (id, obj) =>
  findWith(propEq('id', id), omit(['children']), [obj]);

// found
console.log(findById(1, obj));
console.log(findById(2, obj));
console.log(findById(3, obj));
console.log(findById(4, obj));

// not found
console.log(findById(0, obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {propEq, omit} = R;</script>
<script>
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  name: "first",
  children: [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "second",
      children: []
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "third",
      children: [
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "fourth",
          children: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
</script>
```

Comment: I like this, but really think it could use a gloss for the public function: `const findById = (id, obj) => findWith (propEq ('id', id), pick (['id', 'name']), [obj])`.  Then the API is just `findById (3, obj)`.

Comment: I would probably also argue for `omit (['children'])` over `pick (['id', 'name'])`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Updated accordingly.

Comment: This answer is totaly awesome, thanks! The only thing I wanted to clarify, does it utilizes preferrable "ramda way" of combining functions? You know, no usage of ifElse or pipe functions? It looks elegant, but could it considered to be a "functional" way of problem solving?

Comment: @Cadabrum Your aim is to achieve bigger things out of smaller things. So you usually end up programming with functions and expressions rather than statements. You want your functions pure and side-effect free and keep your data immutable. Ramda definitely helps achieve that but it is not the only way. I have used Ramda for the predicate and transform functions as it provides useful functionalities. I didn't see any need to put more Ramda into the body of the main function. So yeah I'd consider this as a functional solution.

Comment: @Cadabrum: As one of the authors of Ramda, I'd really like to try to eradicate the notion of any "Ramda way".  `pipe` is an extremely useful tool, `ifElse` is a sometimes useful tool, and all the other functions are tools that are to some degree or another useful.  None of them are intended to dictate how you write your code.  This solution presents a pure function; it does not mutate any input data; it uses expressions and not statement; in short, it is a nice example of functional programming.  That it doesn't use Ramda more has no bearing on it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I like the solution from customcommander (especially after my suggestions were incorporated! ;-) ) but I want to note an alternative, using mutual recursion and separating the transformation  function from the find.  The mutual recursion might be overkill here, but it's a useful technique to remember:

```js
const findWithArr = (pred, [x = undefined, ...xs]) => 
  x == undefined
    ? null
    : findWithObj(pred, x) || findWithArr(pred, xs)

const findWithObj = (pred, x) =>
  pred(x)
    ? x
    : findWithArr(pred, x.children || [])

const findAndTransform = (pred, transform, obj, res = findWithObj (pred, obj)) =>
  res && transform (res)

const findById = (id, obj) => 
  findAndTransform(propEq('id', id), omit(['children']), obj)

const obj = {id: 1, name: "first", children: [{id: 2, name: "second", children: []}, {id: 3, name: "third", children: [{id: 4, name: "fourth", children: []}]}]};

// Found
console .log (findById (1, obj))
console .log (findById (2, obj))
console .log (findById (3, obj))
console .log (findById (4, obj))
// Not found
console .log (findById (5, obj))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {propEq, omit} = R                                     </script>
```

Depending on my mood, I might also break down `findAndTransform` a bit more:

```js
const transformNonNull = (transform, val) =>
  val && transform(val)

const findAndTransform = (pred, transform, obj) =>
  transformNonNull (transform, findWithObj (pred, obj))
```